# Move a position absolute image

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

```
$("#plane").animate({
    "opacity"     : 0.8
    "margin-left" : 0
},10000).fadeOut('slow');

<div class="LogoBG">
    <span class="plane" id="plane">
          <img src="<?php echo ROOTPATH ?>img/plane.png" alt="" />
        </span>
</div>


.LogoBG .plane {
    float:right; margin-left:666px;position:absolute;
}
```

I would like to move the object from margin-left:666 to 0. Also i would like to fadeout the image when is in's margin-left property is less than < 333. If that's possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#plane").animate(
  {"margin-left": 333},
  5000,
  'linear', 
  function(){
    $(this).animate(
      {"opacity": 0, "margin-left": 0},
      5000,
      'linear'
    );
  }
);
```

Here is a fiddle to test it: 
http://jsfiddle.net/5BZR3/4/

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#plane").animate({'margin-left': 333}, 1000, 'linear')
               .animate({'margin-left': 0, 'opacity':0}, 1000, 'linear');
});
```

Comment: Definitely slicker than mine. ;)

Comment: @StefanoP: No problem - yours is really cleaner! :)

Comment: @WebDeveloper: There is just a little glitch that makes it defunct. You have to replace 'left' by 'margin-left' in both animations. I have issued an edit that should be approved soon. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Naevt/3/